# Why can't my image be inserted to the database? It only shows a couple of text in the field of the table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob

I have a program that will that a picture from the camera and save it to the database but the data shows up when I browse the blob is **"[B@22e1ae38"** or random letters and numbers and I don't know what is the error.

This is my OnCreate function

```js
@Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                setContentView(R.layout.addstudentsform);
                db=openOrCreateDatabase("ClassManager",MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);

                viewImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.CamPicture);
                viewImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "StudPic.png");
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }

                });
            }
```

This is my onActivity Results:

```js
 @Override
             protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            {
                if (requestCode == 1)
                {

                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                    for (File temp : f.listFiles())
                    {
                        if (temp.getName().equals("StudPic.png"))
                        {
                            f = temp;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        Bitmap bitmap;
                        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
                        viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "Default";
                        OutputStream outFile = null;
                        File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png");

                        try
                        {

                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                            StudImage = bos.toByteArray();
                            f.delete();

                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            displayExceptionMessage(e.getMessage());
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, outFile);
                            outFile.flush();
                            outFile.close();
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

This is the my CreateScreen where I insert the picture in the database as StudPic which is a blob sql type:

```js
 public void CreateScreen (View view)
            {

                EditText  FirstNameText     = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FirstNameText);
                EditText  StudentIDText     = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.StudentIDText);
                EditText  LastNameText      = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastNameText);
                EditText  ContactNumberText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ContactNumberText);
                EditText  EmailAddressText  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailAddressText);

                StudentID     = Integer.parseInt(StudentIDText.getText().toString());
                FirstName     = FirstNameText.getText().toString();
                LastName      = LastNameText.getText().toString();
                ContactNumber = Integer.parseInt(ContactNumberText.getText().toString());
                EmailAddress  = EmailAddressText.getText().toString();

                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MasterStudents (StudPic, StudentID, FirstName, LastName, ContactNumber, EmailAddress) " +
                           "VALUES ('" + StudImage + "','" + StudentID + "','" + FirstName + "','" + LastName + "','" + ContactNumber + "','" + EmailAddress + "');");

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                finish();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Efficient way would be storing the image in FILE SYSTEM not in the database and storing PATH to that image in the database.

Comment: Can you please show me a link? A tutorial that is easy to understand for beginners. Thank you.

Comment: You can get the location of image 'data.getData()' in 'OnActivityResult' method and then you can save it into database as string. And to show that image you can use: 'imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename)' .

Here is a detailed tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the StudPic field is an internal reference to the real blob, a kind of pointer, not the actual bunch of data. So try to read your Blob back from the application and create a Bitmap from that field of the Query, magic shall succeed.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie. Can you try to write the code I want to put?

Comment: I have a tablerow that displays these data and i put in the imageview this: StudImage=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("StudPic"));
            Bitmap b1= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(StudImage, 0, StudImage.length);
            StudImageView.setImageBitmap(b1);